# grails: how to implement a "zero-to-one" relationship

Tags: database, grails, relationship

I need to implement a "zero-to-one" relationship. In particular, I have two classes: Event and Patient; I want that, when I create an event, is possible to choose or not a patient.
I've found something like the following:
in Event class, add a field Patient, with a nullable constraint, but I think that, when I delete the Patient instance, the related events will be not automatically deleted in cascade...
Is there a way to do it automatically? Or do I need to perform it manually?

EDIT:
following your suggestion, I've created a method that deletes events of the patient as follows:

```
 def beforeDelete() {
    new EventController().deleteEventsOfPatient(this)        
}

def deleteEventsOfPatient(Patient patient)
{
    def eventsOfPatient = Event.findAllByPatient(patient)
    for(int i = 0; i < eventsOfPatient.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!eventsOfPatient[i].delete(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "error in delete event of patient";
        }

    }

}
```

but it raises the following exception:

Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.

Comment: Did you read http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/GORM.html#cascades? It should answer your question. Please if possible don't reinvent names for things that already have one - what you have is one-to-one relationship not zero-to-one.

Comment: Now yes! so how to perform the delete manually?

Comment: They will be deleted automatically if you make Patient owning end of the relation using belongsTo. Otherwise you have to delete it manually calling delete method. Either in service or in event handler as Grooveek suggests.

Comment: If I use belongsTo, is it possible to define the field nullable?

Comment: How to delete the Event if I add into it a Patient field nullable?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Grails` doc paragraph titled ['Events and Auto Timestamping'](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

You have a `beforeDelete` event which could be used to delete cleanly your `Patient` if one exists, something like the following :

```
class Patient{

    def beforeDelete() {
         deleteEventsOfPatient()        
    }

    def deleteEventsOfPatient(){
         def eventsOfPatient = Event.findAllByPatient(this)
         for(int i = 0; i < eventsOfPatient.size(); i++){
             eventsOfPatient[i].delete() 
         }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created a method in EventController to delete all events linked to Patient. It is called into the beforeDelete method as you have suggested but I have the following exception: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition. I've edited my question to show you the method.

Comment: If I perform the code above into the delete method of patient controller, before the deletion of patient, everything works, but I don't know if it is the right approach

Comment: You should not perform database operations which needs transactions in controllers, you'll have a lot of problems. You can move these in a persistance service, for which you can control transactional capabilities, or create the method in the Domain itself. We found this to be clearer to maintain

Comment: Ok Grooveek. But how about the exception in previous comment? It is still present if I do operation in Domain as described in your answer. Maybe something is missing?

Comment: The exception is raised because I've used the flush:true in delete(), but if I remove it, the delete does not work